# FPPopover gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS when touch outside of popover view

Tags: iphone, fppopover

I am using FPPopover in my project. I have show popover on UITextField. Popover show properly but after that when i touch outside of popover it gives me EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. ARC is not enable in my project.

Thanks in adv.

Comment: Make that FPPopover Object as a property and check

Comment: @MidhunMP : tried but not worked...

Comment: Have you turned ARC on for FPPopover files?

Comment: @Yogi: How i can make it for particular file ??

Comment: can you share some code

Comment: You can exclude a file from ARC by using flag **-fno-objc-arc** in product settings

Comment: @Yogi: i use this flag **-fobjc-arc**

Comment: Its to make a particular file ARC enabled if your complete project is not supporting ARC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done with little change. I turned on ARC for FPPopover native library file. That solve my issue.